# How to solve Android Studio not installed error in my Flutter project?

Tags: android, flutter

Error:

```
  PS D:\FlutterProjects\NewLedgersFlutter\ledgers_lite_flutter> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.3, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-IN)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
PS D:\FlutterProjects\NewLedgersFlutter\ledgers_lite_flutter> flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Could not find or load main class KUMAR
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: KUMAR
```

Note: I am developing a Flutter project which is giving the above errors when I try to run the application

I have tried with `flutter doctor --android-licenses` but it's not resolving the issues.

Comment: Can you provide us with the output after you use `flutter doctor --android-licenses` please.

Comment: please check above edited code

Answer (score 0):

Try Following Steps

1. Android Studio is installed and you can run it, so when it boots up, select configure: Where to find configure on Android Studio screen
   [image: Refere This Image]
2. In dropdown list open "plugins"
3. Search for "flutter" and install this plugin together with dart.
4. Restart the Android Studio and open a new terminal.
5. You should be able to create a flutter project in Android Studio and "flutter doctor" should work now.

Comment: Setting "android-studio-dir" value to "C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio".

You may need to restart any open editors for them to read new settings.

Comment: if you got android license status unknown try 
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: flutter and dart plugins are already installed

Comment: PS D:\FlutterProjects\NewLedgersFlutter\ledgers_lite_flutter> flutter doctor --android-licenses
Error: Could not find or load main class KUMAR
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: KUMAR

Comment: this is the error i am getting after trying flutter licenses

Comment: try this command `flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Comment: Ok try this steps

1. Open Android Studio
2. Tools > SDK Manager
3. From the left choose, Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK
4. Select SDK Tools from the top menu
5. Check Android SDK Command-line tools and click 'apply'.

Comment: command -line tools also installed already but still the error appears

Comment: Check Android SDK Command-line tools and click 'apply'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234608/discussion-between-vishali-and-ravindra-s-patil).

Answer (score 0):

It should work if you installed Android Studio;

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir="YOUR ANDROID STUDIO PATH"
```

then type flutter doctor to see if it worked

To solve android licence error run;

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

then check it with flutter doctor

Comment: I have android studio but still it is not working

Comment: have you tried this by specifying your directory?

Comment: [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
! Doctor found issues in 1 category.

Comment: type ; flutter doctor --android-licenses  to fix

Comment: i have tried please check my above edited code. i am facing issue after typing flutter doctor --android-licenses

Comment: You need Android SDK Command Line Tools installed. If you're using Android Studio go in Preferences -> Appearance & Behaviour -> System Settings -> Android SDK then select the SKL tools tab and install the latest Android SDK Command Line Tools Did it resolve?