# Exception occured when run flutter doctor --android-licenses

Tags: flutter, android-licenses

I am a flutter beginer, while installing the android license by command "flutter --android-licenses", I have gotten the exception as follows:

```
Failed to create settings
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: port out of range:-1
        at java.base/java.net.InetSocketAddress.checkPort(InetSocketAddress.java:153)
        at java.base/java.net.InetSocketAddress.<init>(InetSocketAddress.java:198)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createAddress(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:177)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.<init>(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:485)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:152)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCliSettings.createSettings(SdkManagerCliSettings.java:134)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:58)
        at com.android.sdklib.tool.sdkmanager.SdkManagerCli.main(SdkManagerCli.java:49)
```

I try to search solution a lot of, but I have no result. So could everyone help me?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68282677/13997210) hope its help to you

**Or Try below steps:**

1. Open Tools > SDK Manager
2. From the left choose, Appearance & Behavior > System Settings > Android SDK
3. Select SDK Tools from the top menu
4. Check Android SDK Command-line tools and click 'apply'.

Comment: I did it, but the problem still existing

Comment: the same problem is occurred?

Comment: That's right.....

Comment: are you install `latest` command line version? if you complete all above steps Then click the OK button to finish the installation.